# "keras.backend.variable" is not behaving correctly in keras as opposed to tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, variables, keras, parameters

I want to define trainable scalar in my models. In TensorFlow, this is done using `tf.Variable`. In Keras, `keras.backend.variable` is supposed to behave the same way. However, when I use `model.fit`, `keras` does not change the `variable` during the optimization process. Does anyone know why?

To test, please uncomment `RUN_ON = "tensorflow"` or `RUN_ON = "keras"` to run on either of engines.

```
import numpy as np
import keras as k
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# RUN_ON = "tensorflow"
# RUN_ON = "keras"


b_true = 3.0
w_true = 5.0
x_true = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 1000).reshape(-1, 1)
y_true = x_true * w_true + b_true
ids = np.arange(0, x_true.shape[0])

if RUN_ON=="keras":
    x = k.Input((1,), dtype="float32", name="x")
    Fx = k.layers.Dense(1, use_bias=False, name="Fx")(x)
    b = k.backend.variable(1.0, name="b")
    y = k.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x+b, name="Add")(Fx)

    model = k.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=[y])
    model.compile("adam", loss="mse")
    # model.summary()

    model.fit(x_true, [y_true], epochs=100000, batch_size=1000)
    y_pred = model.predict(x_true)

elif RUN_ON=="tensorflow":
    x = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[None, 1], name="x")
    Fx = tf.layers.Dense(1, use_bias=False, name="Fx")(x)
    b = tf.Variable(1.0, name="b")
    y = Fx + b
    yp = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=[None, 1], name="y")

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(yp - y))
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for i in range(100000):
            np.random.shuffle(ids)
            opt_out, loss_val, b_val = sess.run([opt, loss, b], feed_dict={x: x_true[ids], yp: y_true[ids]})
            print("epoch={:d}  loss={:e}   b_val={:f}".format(i, loss_val, b_val))
            if loss_val < 1.0e-9:
                break

        y_pred = sess.run([y], feed_dict={x: x_true, yp: y_true})[0]

else:
    raise ValueError('`RUN_ON` should be either `keras` or `tensorflow`.')

plt.plot(x_true, y_true, '--b', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(x_true, y_pred, 'r')
plt.show()
#
```

Comment: You should [define a custom layer in Keras](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) if you want to have trainable parameters.

Comment: That's what I just did actually, however, I am wondering 1) why `k.backend.variable` is not functioning properly even though it says a trainable parameter in the description and 2) is there any build-in way in keras?

Comment: Where does it say "trainable" in Keras?

Comment: I inferred indirectly from the following description in the function's definition" 

`constraint: Optional projection function to be applied to the variable after an optimizer update`

If it is not trainable, why an optimizer update matters?